# wait till media selection in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

I am working with the **MPMediaPickerController** controller.

Right now I am able to select an item from the gallery using the following code:

```
MPMediaPickerController *controller = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc]initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
controller.delegate = mediaDelegate._pickerDelegate;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
NSLog(@"url :%@",singleton.url);
```

The intention is that my method should return the URL of the selected item. Instead I am getting `null` for the URL because the line below the present view controller gets called  as soon as view controller presented (it is not waiting for selection of item).

Is there any way to stop after `presentViewController`, for selection of item and then return the selected item URL from the method ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate` delegate:

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
```

When the user selects an item, that method will be called

Comment: i have already have that method . But before I select that method the control returns from the upper method from which I am calling [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];  and hence I am getting null url

Comment: I dont think you understand how a delegate works. You need to wait to the user to select that, and the delegate will be called, you cannot stop the run of your program in order to wait to a selection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
NSLog(@"url :%@",singleton.url);
```

in

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
```

method..

Comment: @user3057042: Because in your code you are present controller after immdtly of creation. you need to implement in delegate method.

Comment: So, when user select some item then after delegate method is called in and present your controller.

Comment: @user3057042: as Antonio MG said ,i dont think you understand how a delegate works. You need to wait to the user to select that, and the delegate will be called, you cannot stop the run of your program in order to wait to a selection.